# Dificuldade em remover child, Python

Tags: python

Bom dia amigos. Estou com dificuldade em remover um child. Escrevi um código pra coletar todos os preços dos produtos de um site (se trata de uma lista de produtos, e não uma página pra cada um). Quanto a isto sem problemas, o código funciona bem. Acontece que às vezes algum produto entra em promoção, e no site ficam 2 preços, o antigo e o novo (em desconto), e o meu código puxa ambos. O preço antigo não é interessante, então queria ignorá-lo quando estiver puxando os dados, mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso acontecer. Um exemplo do código fonte:

```
<div class="result-actions"
  <span> ==$0
    $ 1,98
  </span>
<div class="result-actions">
  <span>
    <small class="price-before"> ==$0
      $ 56,70
    </small>
    <span class="price-now">
      $ 39,60
    </span>
  </span>
```

Cada "result-actions" representa um produto. Me sugeriram puxar o "price-now", mas neste caso o primeiro produto do exemplo não seria puxado pelo meu código, já que ele não está em promoção e por isso não contém a classe. 
O meu código tentando excluir o child, mas sem sucesso:

```
with open('Lista.csv') as example_file:
  example_reader = csv.reader(example_file)
  for row in example_reader:
      driver.get(row[0])
      html = driver.page_source
      bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
      precosLista = bs.findAll('div',{'class':'result-actions'})
      f = open(acha_proximo_nome('Arquivo.csv'), 'wt+', newline='')
      writer = csv.writer(f)

      try:
          for precos in precosLista:
              print(precos.get_text())
              csvPreco = []
              csvPreco.append(clean_up_text(precos.get_text()))
              js = "var aa = document.getElementsByClassName('price-before')[0];aa.parentNode.removeChild(aa)"
              driver.execute_script(js)
              writer.writerow(csvPreco)

      finally:
          f.close()
```

Sem o

```
js = "var aa = document.getElementsByClassName('price-before')[0];aa.parentNode.removeChild(aa)"
driver.execute_script(js)
```

meu código roda bem, mas é como falei, coleta tudo, inclusive o que não quero. Alguém tem idéia de como posso corrigir isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já que você esta usando o BeautifulSoup, você pode usar o método [replace_with](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) que cada node contem. Ele permite você trocar o conteúdo da tag por um html especifico. No caso eu troquei o conteúdo por uma string vazia no exemplo do código abaixo:

```
import bs4

html = '''<div class="result-actions">
<span>
  $ 1,98
</span>
</div>
<div class="result-actions">
<span>
  <small class="price-before">
    $ 56,70
  </small>
  <span class="price-now">
    $ 39,60
  </span>
</span>
</div>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(markup=html)
prices = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'result-actions'})

for price in prices:
    # remove o preco antigo
    smalls = price.find_all('small')
    for small in smalls:
        small.replace_with('')

    value = price.find_all('span')[0].text.strip()
    print (value)
```

O resultado desse código deve imprimir os valores corretamente para esse HTML:

```
> $ 1,98
> $ 39,60
```

Comment: Cara, perfeito! Funcionou que é uma maravilha! E pra vc ver, é uma solução simples até, mas que nem passou pela cabeça! hahaha Obrigado, de verdade! Resolveu 2 dias de quebração de cabeça :p